# what's the point of System.IO.Error

Tags: exception, haskell

I noticed there is a [IOException](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:IOException) type in Control.Exception as well, what's the point of having a separate System.IO.Error module and IOError type? Is it there just because of historical reasons? Should I avoid using it and prefer Control.Exception.IOException?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is just for historical reasons.

`System.IO.Error` has an `IOError` type which is just a type synonym for `IOException` (in GHC anyways).

GHCs fancy exception hierarchy mechanism is not part of the Haskell standard.  So, `IOError` is used for compatability with Haskell 2010.

If you are happy with being GHC specific, `IOException` and the entire Exception hierarchy is simply better and should be preferred.

Comment: thanks, am I right any new development would prefer Control.Exception.IOException? Is there any other such historical modules still wildly used/taught on internet?

Comment: @Gwenc37 Please don't use code ticks on things that aren't code.

Answer (score 3):

IOError is the old [Haskell98 IO exception](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) type. Control.Exception and other newer variants are not necessarily Haskell98-compatible, but we can embed the old Haskell98 errors in them, hence the type synonym.